# I'm first at C++. and i encountered some p about class

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm first at C++. I'm using Xcode IDE. I encountered some problem about class. I don't know much about programming so I don't know why it can't read `setScore()`.

[image: code screeny]

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not post pictures of text. Instead, copy your code and put int into the question - this way we can copy it if needed, and also it is much easier to read.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy-paste the actual code, as text, into the question body instead. Please edit your question to include the text as code, and then copy-paste the *build* errors into the question (still as text, and preferably all of the output or build log) too, marking out (with e.g. a comment) where the errors are.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but once you manage to build your program you will have *undefined behavior* when you run it. This is because you call `p1.ShowScore()` before any of the member variables in `p1` have been initialized.

Comment: Thank you all of you! i do not post picture again.

Comment: You can improve your question right now by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41931911/edit) it.